# How to make hover smooth? C# Winforms

Tags: c#

Sup, want to ask how to make my hover smooth? I'm just replacing button image on hover.

```
private void button1_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.HoverState.Image = WindowsFormApp1.Properties.Resources.btn_hovered;
}

private void button1_unhover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
    button1.HoverState.Image = WindowsFormApp1.Properties.Resources.DefImg;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing with this code?

Comment: @Marco I want to ask what I should do to make a transition before changing button img. So it's just example code.

Comment: I'd go with a _transition_, hoping you can avoid flickering...